# Accumulation of files in pg_repslots folder in PostgreSQL + Debezium

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have multiple PostgreSQL clusters, some in version 11 and others in version 13. Usually, I have between 5 to 30 databases being replicated by Debezium (2.0.1) in each cluster. The size of each database varies from 1GB to 300GB, and they all have the same schema.

The applications connected to these databases are quite old and legacy. At some random point, I notice that the replications stop in one of the clusters. The Debezium logs don't provide any clues, but the CPU load becomes very high, and the pg_repslots folder starts accumulating files.

In these cases, I'm unable to even stop the PID of the replication slot. To restore normal operation, I have to stop Kafka Connect, restart PostgreSQL, and delete the replication slots. If I only restart the services, the problem persists, and Debezium is unable to catch up with the last LSN, resulting in the message **Searching for WAL resume position (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource:323)**.

If I don't delete the replication slots, the pg_repslots folder consumes all available disk space.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide any direction on what I should investigate?

Comment: WALs will accumulate when either the communication between the publisher and subscriber is lost, or the subscriber is unable to replay the changes. You'll need to identify what is happening; since you provide no useful details (you describe symptoms, but not causes), it's unlikely that anyone might be able to help.